# Debit Credit Balance calculating from previous records with Pagination

Tags: mysql, postgresql, subquery

I have a table which contains the following data:

```
ID      In       Out 
1      100.00    0.00   
2       10.00    0.00   
3        0.00   70.00    
4        5.00    0.00    
5        0.00   60.00   
6       20.00    0.00
```

Now I need a query which gives me the following result:

```
ID      In       Out    Balance
1      100.00    0.00   100.00
2       10.00    0.00   110.00
3        0.00   70.00    40.00
4        5.00    0.00    45.00
5        0.00   60.00   -15.00
6       20.00    0.00     5.00
```

Is it possible to do this with one query, without using **a trigger** or **temp variables** or **stored procedures**? Also will work with pagination on table/grid.

I made this question from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9394418/calculate-balance-with-mysql) i still don't have the answer for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this bro, for a `quick` solution:

```
-- Run this at first to set starting value at zero 
SET @variable = 0;
-- Without Pagination
SELECT        ID, `In`, `Out`, @variable := @variable + (`In` - `Out`) `Balance`
FROM          <your_table>
ORDER BY      ID ASC;
-- With Pagination
SELECT        ID, `In`, `Out`, @variable := @variable + (`In` - `Out`) `Balance`
FROM          <your_table>
ORDER BY      ID ASC
LIMIT         0 /* INDEX FOR THE START */, 5 /* NUMBER OF DISPLAYED ITEMS */;
```

Sample Result:

[image]

I hope this one can `help/guide` you into your problem, cheers!

Comment: You _must_ include an `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 3):

As you have also tagged it with Postgres:

```
select id, 
       "in", 
       "out", 
       sum("in") over (order by id) - sum("out") over (order by id) as balance
from data
order by id;
```

The above is not Postgres specific, it's standard ANSI SQL using window functions.

Online example: http://rextester.com/ENBLS73027

To add pagination, use `row_number()`

```
select id, "in", "out", balance
from (
  select id, 
         "in", 
         "out", 
         sum("in") over (order by id) - sum("out") over (order by id) as balance, 
         row_Number() over (order by id) as rn
  from data
) t
where rn between 3 and 6 -- rows 3,4,5 and 6
order by id;
```