# calculate running balance of debit credit using union all

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

i'm making account statement for which i need that account balance before today and with each transaction  row of `debit` or `credit` plus and minus from initial opening balance on the basis debit/credit amount rules....
for this i'm using this approach

```
SELECT '1'AS VoucherNo,''AS DocumentDate,'Opening' AS Description,isnull(SUM(JournalDetials.Debit),0)AS Debit,
    isnull(SUM(JournalDetials.Credit),0)AS Credit,(isnull(SUM(JournalDetials.Debit),0)-isnull(SUM(JournalDetials.Credit),0))[Balance],
    ''as JournalTransationStatus
    FROM JournalDetials INNER JOIN JournalMains ON JournalDetials.JournalMainId = JournalMains.Id
    INNER JOIN GLMainAccount ON JournalDetials.GLMainAccountId=GLMainAccount.Id
    where(JournalDetials.AccountId='001653')AND(JournalDetials.Date<'03/31/2019')

    union all

    select(JournalMains.VoucherNumberPrefix+JournalMains.VoucherNumber)AS VoucherNo,JournalDetials.Date as DocumentDate,
    isnull(JournalDetials.Description,''),isnull(JournalDetials.Debit,0),isnull(JournalDetials.Credit,0),''[Balance],
    ''JournalTransationStatus
    from JournalDetials inner join JournalMains on JournalDetials.JournalMainId = JournalMains.Id
    INNER JOIN GLMainAccount ON JournalDetials.GLMainAccountId = GLMainAccount.Id
where(JournalDetials.AccountId='001653' and JournalDetials.Date BETWEEN '03/31/2019' AND '04/09/2020')
```

[image]

I was trying to apply [this solution](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/162393/debit-credit-balance-calculating-from-previous-records-with-pagination) but couldn't able to run this in SQL 2008 [due to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38065881/sql-server-2012-sum-over-order-by-gives-error-incorrect-syntax-near-order). so now, how to calculate running balance total along with each debit credit value in SQL 2008?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310877/calculate-running-total-running-balance

Comment: already tried. due to large data and multiple joins query slows down...

Answer (score 1):

Try this (you may need to adjust data types or play with clustered index on temporary table, may be use identity column):

```
CREATE TABLE #x(
VoucherNo int, 
DocumentDate datetime, 
Description varchar(255), 
Debit numeric(18,2), 
Credit numeric(18,2),
Balance numeric(18,2)
);
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX cx_x ON #x(DocumentDate, VoucherNo);

INSERT INTO #x (VoucherNo, DocumentDate, Description, Debit, Credit)
SELECT '1'AS VoucherNo,''AS DocumentDate,'Opening' AS Description,isnull(SUM(JournalDetials.Debit),0)AS Debit,
    isnull(SUM(JournalDetials.Credit),0)AS Credit
    FROM JournalDetials INNER JOIN JournalMains ON JournalDetials.JournalMainId = JournalMains.Id
    INNER JOIN GLMainAccount ON JournalDetials.GLMainAccountId=GLMainAccount.Id
    where(JournalDetials.AccountId='001653')AND(JournalDetials.Date<'03/31/2019')

    union all

    select(JournalMains.VoucherNumberPrefix+JournalMains.VoucherNumber)AS VoucherNo,JournalDetials.Date as DocumentDate,
    isnull(JournalDetials.Description,''),isnull(JournalDetials.Debit,0),isnull(JournalDetials.Credit,0)
    from JournalDetials inner join JournalMains on JournalDetials.JournalMainId = JournalMains.Id
    INNER JOIN GLMainAccount ON JournalDetials.GLMainAccountId = GLMainAccount.Id
where(JournalDetials.AccountId='001653' and JournalDetials.Date BETWEEN '03/31/2019' AND '04/09/2020')

DECLARE @Balance numeric(18,2), @DocumentDate datetime, @amt numeric(18,2), @VoucherNo int;
SET @Balance = 0;

DECLARE c CURSOR LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY
  FOR SELECT DocumentDate, VoucherNo, Debit - Credit FROM #x ORDER BY DocumentDate, VoucherNo;

OPEN c;

FETCH c INTO @DocumentDate, @VoucherNo, @amt;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  SET @Balance = @Balance + @amt;
  UPDATE #x SET Balance = @Balance WHERE DocumentDate = @DocumentDate AND VoucherNo = @VoucherNo;
  FETCH c INTO @DocumentDate, @VoucherNo, @amt;
END

CLOSE c; DEALLOCATE c;

SELECT VoucherNo, DocumentDate, Description, Debit, Credit, Balance, '' AS JournalTransationStatus
  FROM #x 
  ORDER BY DocumentDate, VoucherNo;

DROP TABLE #x;
```