# Debit Credit Balance calculating from previous records with Pagination MYSQL

Tags: mysql, query, subquery

I have table with the following schema and demo data-

```
id  date        particulars          debit  credit  
104 29-12-2020  Crediting            NULL   1000    
105 29-12-2020  Purchased Item:A     2000   NULL    
106 29-12-2020  Purchased Item:B     200    NULL    
107 29-12-2020  Purchased Item:C     1000   NULL    
108 29-12-2020  Credited             NULL   1200    
109 29-12-2020  Credited             NULL   500     
110 29-12-2020  Credited             NULL   2100    
111 29-12-2020  Credited             NULL   1300    
112 01-01-2021  Purchased Item:Q     200    NULL    
113 02-01-2021  Purchased Item:A     2300   NULL
```

I want to calcualte running balance along with filters like from this date to this and pagination included.
So far by referring this [Answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/162393/debit-credit-balance-calculating-from-previous-records-with-pagination)
I found the satisfied results, only the problem lies with `WHERE` clause.

Query i have used =

```
SET @variable = 0;
SELECT id, date, particulars, debit, credit, @variable := @variable + (COALESCE(`credit`,0) - COALESCE(`debit`,0)) `balance` 
FROM billing_ledger  ORDER BY id asc
```

when i use this query im not getting expected balance as it should be

```
SET @variable = 0;
SELECT id, date, particulars, debit, credit, @variable := @variable + (COALESCE(`credit`,0) - COALESCE(`debit`,0)) `balance` 
FROM billing_ledger where date >= '2021-01-01' ORDER BY id asc
```

i want this second query to also consider the above rows but to give me results for the following dates with `where` clause and also with `LIMIT`

Here is the fiddle: [FiddleLink](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=7eb6d974657dadcb0c7791df1bd60991)

In fiddle, we can see that the second query is not considering the rows above, and thus the balance is not correct as it is in the 1st query.

Comment: Tag with the version of MySQL you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using the user-defined variables to iterate and so calculating the balnace, you have to set the initial variable ti the right amount

> ```
> SET @variable = 0;
> SELECT
> -SUM(debit)  + SUM(credit) INTO @variable
> FROM billing_ledger where date < '2021-01-01';
> SELECT id, date, particulars, debit, credit
> , @variable := @variable + (COALESCE(`credit`,0) - COALESCE(`debit`,0)) `balance` 
> FROM billing_ledger where date >= '2021-01-01' ORDER BY id asc ;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
>  id | date       | particulars           | debit | credit | balance
> --: | :--------- | :-------------------- | ----: | -----: | ------:
> 112 | 2021-01-01 | Purchased Item: Eggs  |   200 |   null |    2700
> 113 | 2021-01-02 | Purchased Item: Onion |  2300 |   null |     400
> ```

Comment: thanks this worked perfectly

Comment: How do you make a pagination work with this query? The initial value of the @variable will always be the same at the beginning of each paginated set.

Comment: in mysql You use LIMIT and  OFFSET to add pagnation